# "Detection limit" and "reporting limit" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

At work we measure chemicals and there are normally limits (in for example mg/kg) for these substances. There is a limit for when a substance is detected (anything below it is "not detected", even though there "is" a number). Then there is a limit at which one would report it - this might be higher or the same as the detection limit. How would these be named in Esperanto?

Answer (score 2):

Although I've never seen this used, and there is no exact translation, I would recommend the following:

Detection limit:

> Detektebla nombro
>
> Detectable number

Reporting limit:

> Raportenda / raportinda nombro
>
> Number that must be reported / is worth reporting

Comment: @JohannesMueller thanks - I've switched it to "nombro."